# PHP Notice: 'Array to string conversion' while making symfony form template

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm following [A symfony tutorial in the official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html).
However When I get to [Field Type Options](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#field-type-options) symfony throws the error
"An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Array to string conversion") in form_div_layout.html.twig at line 13."

I have checked on google and typos, the offending line, from the documentation seems to be:

```
->add('dueDate', DateType::class, array('widget' => 'single_text'))
```

Which is straight from the documentation.
For context the rest of the file looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Entity\Task;

use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="homepage")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        // replace this example code with whatever you need
        return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', [
            'base_dir' => realpath($this->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').'/..'),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/form", name="formmma")
     */
    public function newAction(Request $request)
    {
        // create a task and give it some dummy data for this example
        $task = new Task();
        $task->setTask('Write a blog post');

        $task->setDueDate(new \DateTime('tomorrow'));

        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($task)
            ->add('task', TextType::class)
           // ->add('dueDate', DateType::class)
            ->add('dueDate', DateType::class, array('widget' => 'single_text'))
           // ->add('dueDate', null, array(
           //     'widget' => 'single_text',
           //     'required' => false
           // ))

            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Create Task'))
            ->getForm();

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
             // ... perform some action, such as saving the task to the database

             return $this->redirectToRoute('task_success');
        }

        return $this->render('default/new.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your array???

Comment: the array that throws the error is  "array('widget' => 'single_text')"

Comment: I tried exactly same code in my testing environment and it worked. So IMHO you should do two things - 1) check if form_div_layout.html.twig is not modified, 2) clear symfony cache

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this issue? I'm currently having the exact same problem. My layout file is not modified and I tried clearing the cache...

Comment: I'm also running into this bug and I tracked it down to `Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig`
`value` contains an array with day, month and year value but is used like this `value="{{ value }}"`.

So it's obvious why it fails but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

in your controller put

```
     if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
        $dateFrom=$booking->dateOfArrival;
        $booking->dateOfArrival= new \DateTime();
        $booking->dateOfArrival->setDate($dateFrom->format('Y'),$dateFrom->format('m'),$dateFrom->format('d'));}
```

PS: "booking" is the model used in the form